# How to display and input large amount data in a datagrid-like table on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, datagrid, tabular

I am working on a iPhone based MIS, I need to make a table to show large amount of data from core data, edit some of them, then save them. The table could have tens of columns and hundreds of rows.

So it's there anything like the datagrid in ASP.NET on iPhone? If not, how can I input lots of data in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a `UIScrollView` is designed to display content of an arbitrary width/height, and a `UITableView` provides an interface through which you can display a table of arbitrary length.  `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. It's a good starting point - even if you end up not using the class itself and implementating your own version - because it will show you the right approach to view recycling.

There is no in-built class for displaying a 'spreadsheet', which I assume is what you're after. So you'll either need to roll your own from scratch, or see if you can hack/modify a UITableView enough to give you what you want. You may want to look at some of the existing spreadsheet apps for hints/clues as to how they've achieved it. I'm sorry to say there's no simple way within iOS to do what you're after, so be prepared for some work!

Comment: hi @lxt, do you know any existing spreadsheet app on iOS? I have never found one. Any open source spreadsheet lib could be much more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same sort of thing and threw this together. It reuses rows like the UITableView and can be bound to a variety of data sources. I've implemented two datasources, one is for static data, and the second allows you to bind to an NSFetchedResultsController.

I have tested it with an NSFetchedResultsController connected to a CoreData store that contains hundreds of thousands of rows of data on the iPhone 4S and it performs very well. There is room for expansion and if there is any demand for this sort of thing, I will continue to develop and support it.

https://github.com/AlanSamet/ASDataGridView

Answer (score 1):

This [iOS data grid](http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-data-grid-table-view/586) might be what you need - both tabular data and scrolling. It's not free, but looks like it provides functionality that would take significant time to implement so you might want to check it out.

Comment: My current solution is create customer `UITableViewCell` in Interface Builder with `UILabel`s and `UITextField`s. For now it works fine. However your link makes me think I should make it more common, to be used in future projects.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use UIWebView. What you do is create the HTML for your table dynamically in your code. I then used the UIWebView method loadHTMLString: baseURL: (note: baseURL can be nil) to load my generated HTML string.

As for styling, I embedded the css in the HTML I generated in the head section or you can use inline styling.

Also, be sure to:

- Add in the HTML5 doctype.
- The viewport meta tags.
- Set userInteractionEnabled to NO.
- Set dataDetectionTypes to UIDataDetectorTypeNone.
- To escape those double quotes if you are using NSMutableString to generate your HTML code.

HIH

Comment: Thanks. I don't know much about html or css, but I think this could be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

In my research on this topic, here are a few links that I have found:

https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView (Free)

http://ioscomponents.com/Home/Products (Commercial - lots of features 29 USD)

https://www.developergarden.com/en/marketplace/components/details/cmp/ios-data-grid-table-view (commercial 129 USD)

http://www.binpress.com/app/vertical-horizontal-scrolling-datagrid-for-ios/1082 (Commercial)